# Долой бесполезные комментарии вроде "спасибо"

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, комментарии, шаблонные-комментарии

Давайте программно не позволять комментарии вроде "Спасибо" и т.д., а рекомендовать проголосовать за и/или принять ответ.

На enSO это для некоторых видов комментариев это реализовано

[image: Comment forbidden]

Возможно это будет стимулировать пользователей голосовать за и принимать ответ. Зато гарантированно не будет лишних комментариев.

Comment: +1. Хорошее предложение!

Comment: Спасибо за отличную идею! `[сарказм]`

Comment: Т.е разделение полов сложно сделать, а убрать комментарий спасибо - отличная идея? ))))
Хоть запретите вообще писать комменты, если человек не захочет голосовать или отмечать ответом, то хоть что делайте))

Comment: @Elena 1. Тут просто текста по регулярному выражению. Намного проще в реализации, чем разделении полов. 2. Уже реализовано на enSO, осталось только применить для нас. 3. Может быть полезно для всех языков, а не для некоторых. 4. Я не писал что 100% проголосует. Просто подскажет, что здесь принято выражать "Спасибо" через голос за или принятый ответ. Потому что не все люди знают от том как принять ответ, и что можно проголосовать за.
5. Удалит гарантированно лишний комментарий, не несущий никакой смысловой нагрузки.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, это называется Вам уже заняться нечем! )

Comment: @Elena Кстати разделение полов, это другой функционал и этому никак не противоречит. Между прочим я против этой реализации не возражал.

Comment: Совсем ороботились? И плюс к этому, видимо, еще и "болезнь красных глаз" (в данном случае гонка за репой).

Comment: @avp Не разглядел конструктива в вашем комментарие. Плюс похоже на переход на личности.

Comment: @alexolut никто не понял наших шуток :(

Comment: @NickVolynkin ещё и тему минусуют ... ага.

Comment: @Elena это у нас с alexolut был сарказм. Мы ответили точно такими комментариями, которые предлагается блокировать.

Comment: @avp про роботов поддерживаю, а вот про красные глаза и репу как-то непонятно. Вы хотели указать автору на какую-то его ошибку? Если так, не могли бы вы это переформулировать в конструктивном ключе?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, нет у него никаких ошибок, кроме вызывающих раздражение предложений.

Comment: Я всеми руками за)

Answer (score 10):

Есть альтернативное предложение, некий гибрид уже упомянутых идей.

Вместо блокирования комментариев, содержащих "+1", "спасибо" и т.п., выводить подсказку вида:

> Если вопрос/ответ вам интересен проголосуйте за него (стрелки слева)

Для комментариев вида "спасибо" от ТС выводить:

> Если ответ решил вашу проблему - примите его, путём установки галочки слева.

Все эти подсказки дополнить кнопками:

<kbd>Всё равно хочу опубликовать комментарий</kbd> и <kbd>Отказаться от комментария</kbd>.

Текст сообщений подсказок и кнопок можно обсудить, но основная идея именно в том, что мы даём участнику понять, какие действия будут являться более подходящими вместо увеличения информационного шума и использования комментариев не по назначению.

Comment: Почему комментарий в виде "Спасибо" под ответом является информационным шумом и не по назначению если ответ **решил** проблему?  В чем заключается шум? Будет мешать другим обсуждать ответ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это не я придумал. Посмотрите на текст, который выводится в поле комментария пока еще ничего не введено.

Comment: Против, потому что вы предлагаете разработчикам реализовать новую фичу для решения проблемы, реальность которой не подтверждена.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ТС привел картинку же. Думаете, это фейк?

Comment: @alexolut нет, но там другая фича. Вы предлагаете добавить кнопки и не блокировать, а просто подсказывать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin предпосылки те же. А фича, безусловно, другая. Какой смысл повторять то, что уже существует при высказывании **нового предложения**?

Comment: @alexolut насколько я понял, предложение в том, чтобы расширить регулярное выражение, которое проверяет комментарии, добавив в него "спасибо" и некоторые другие слова русского языка.

Comment: По моему, это идеальный компромисс, который никому ничем не помешает. Просто подсказки, которые будут советовать либо отметить ответ как принятый, либо проголосать за. Если надо, можем сделать чтобы было до определённого уровня репутации.

Answer (score 7):

Думаю, что проверка регулярками и блокирование таких комментариев были реализованы с конкретными целями:

- мотивировать участников голосовать за ответы (вместо написания "+1")
- рекомендовать тем же участникам писать конструктивные комментарии о достоинствах ответа
- напоминать авторам вопросов, что желательно ставить галочки (а "спасибо" это сигнал о том, что ответ привёл к решению проблемы)

Просто так запрещать какие-то комментарии потому что они нам кажутся нерациональными или потому что у нас есть техническая возможность запрещать — бессмысленное и, возможно, опасное занятие.

*Давайте для начала выясним, есть ли проблема? Много ли у нас "+1" в комментариях, часто ли пишут "спасибо" **вместо** постановки галочки?*

Если автор поставил галочку и написал в комментарии «спасибо, ваш ответ помог мне понять ... и сделать ...» — это же здорово, это приятно, это ценная награда для автора вопроса.
Возможно, более ценная, чем +25 репутации за плюс и галочку.
На мой взгляд, такой комментарий не создаёт какого-то запредельного шума на сайте, чтобы его нужно было запрещать.
А ещё это как-то не по-человечески, отвечать участнику, что он не может поблагодарить словами.
В этом я согласен с avp.

Итого:

- Про «+1» хотелось бы увидеть статистику, подтверждающую наличие проблемы.
- Про «спасибо» — категорически против запрета. Давайте лучше писать авторам напоминания про галочку (не автоматически, а лично, руками).

Comment: Фуууф. Облегченно выдохнул. А то я тоже реально не понял, что вы пошутили в комментариях.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский добавил табличку «сарказм»

Comment: @NickVolynkin хорошо наверное иметь возможность править свои комменты и после пятиминутного интервала...

Comment: @alexolut ещё как ) могу ваше поправить

Comment: @NickVolynkin зачем? моё без сарказма. `[сарказм]`

Comment: Комментарий с только "+1" и "спасибо" невозможно оставить технически, так как минимальная длинна комментария 15 символов.

Comment: @МаркИз дело в подстроках.