# Отклонены тревоги "более не является необходимым" и другие казусы модерации комментариев

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, модерация, тревоги, комментарии

На enSO у меня на момент написания более 600 тревог. Почти все были приняты, а если и нет, то я со временем понимал логику и закономерности почему так. У нас же куча разных казусов и как-то и без логики, как мне кажется, в плане модерации комментариев.

Вот примеры комментариев, тревоги на которые "более не является необходимым" были отклонены:

- [Спасибо, действительно помогло! :)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/678738/678745#comment993927_678745)
- [спасибо большое! то, что нужно было изначально!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/294962/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b0-option-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-value-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be/295052#comment295122_295052)
- [Решение на стороне сервера есть, спасибо за него Роману Жукову.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/294962/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b0-option-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-value-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be#comment295120_294962) Я считаю, что просто комментарий вида "спасибо", который подлежит уничтожению.
- [Решение на стороне клиента найдено! Спасибо за него Ridzhi!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/294962/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b0-option-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-value-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be#comment295123_294962) То же самое, что и выше.
- [Спасибо большое!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/681442/%d0%97%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-border-%d0%b2-css/681455#comment999780_681455)
- [Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/372478/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8b#comment372555_372478). Это уже было сделано, зачем комментарий?
- [Да я над ответом думал ))))). Нашел в справочнике описание как раз подходящее)). Что ж, буду пробовать...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/372478/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8b#comment372557_372478) Комментраий-ответ автора на прошлый комментарий.
- [Спасибо огромное!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/788224/%d0%a1%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8#comment1240334_788224)
- [Гениально, спасибо)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/785839/%d0%a3%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-flex-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d1%80/785880#comment1235239_785880)
- [Спасибо большое!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/197812/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-div-%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83/197814#comment197817_197814)
- [То что надо! Просто и легко! Спасибо.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/772576/%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-border-css/772765#comment1207561_772765)
- [Спасибо большое!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609372/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0/609374#comment834411_609374)
- [тоже раньше об этом думал, думал есть альтернатива, спасибо!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/733924/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8/733929#comment1116334_733929) Комментарий вида "я тоже, спасибо", зачем он?
- [Пожалуйста!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/733924/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8/733929#comment1116344_733929)
- [Огромнейшее спасибо, сразу видно руку мастера своего дела!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/699597/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-tooltip#comment1037791_699622)

Далее идут другого плана тревоги

- [Вы случайно не индус? `$postRub = array('1'=>'nnn1' ... '65'=>'nnn65'}; $rub = $postRub[$_POST['rub']]`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/294962/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b0-option-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-value-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be/294968#comment295066_294968) Могу ошибаться, но звучит оскорбительно.
- [наверное сложно было помочь написав 1 строчку, да? $(window).load().](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/699168/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b#comment1036962_699168) Считаю данный комментарий "невежливым или оскорбительным". Но его почему-то оставили.
- [Українську корисно знати..](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/537915/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-css-%d0%b2-jsp-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-mvc-resources/606239#comment826415_606239). Это по-украински "Украинский язык полезно знать". Участник мне это ответил на предложение перевести вопрос на русский. Я оставил тревогу с описанием "Автор украинского ответа считает, что переводить на русский не стоит, так как украинский полезно знать." **Почему-то модератор данную тревогу отклонил**, но сам ответ взял и перевёл (я не понимаю почему надо было отвергать, тревога же полезная). Комментарии на украинском почему-то не удалил. Мне тут логику модератора не понять.

---

Вот как-то так.

Comment: Попробуйте более специфичный заголовок (и примеры): «Предлагаю, удалять комментарии, содержащие "Спасибо"». Другие примеры к вопросу не относятся (можно отдельно обсудить).

Comment: @jfs Да не хочется как-то ещё 3 поста отдельно создавать. Но может быть в будущем сделаю.

Comment: @jfs Это зависит от реакции на этот пост. Может вообще нет смысла стараться? На англоязычных сайтах такого не возникает, а если и возникает, то модераторы или признают это [ошибкой](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338504/1548895), или даже [извиняются](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279776/346987). Но не у нас…

Comment: @jfs Забавно также то, что мои тревоги отклонял не PashaPash, а кто-то другой. И несмотря на то, что все остальные модераторы были онлайн в течение суток, никто не отвечает. На enSO загрузки в разы больше, но модераторы отвечают очень быстро и чётко объясняют, почему так произошло. И вообще такая ерунда в таких кол-вах не происходит. Мой ответ почти сразу удалили из-за одного слова, которое не понравилось модератору, не дав даже отредактировать.

Comment: @jfs С флагами на посты у меня тоже случались подобные казусы и почему-то только у нас. Нужно пост для каждого случая? Не знаю, надо ли на это тратиться. Я боюсь, что будет также, как и с этим постом. Я уже не верю в добросовестную модерацию у нас.

Comment: если не было решения об удалении таких комментариев, то почему вы думаете модераторы должны это делать (если было уже решение, то явную ссылку добавьте)¶ Лучше меньше акцент на личности делать, а больше акцент на как можно улучшить сайт. Обозначить *конкретную* проблему: "я думаю что комментарии-благодарности вредят по X,Y, Z причинам". И как исправить, к примеру: "запретить короткие комментарии со словом спасибо" или "удалять комментарии автоматически по одной тревоге, если они содержат слово спасибо" итд.

Comment: @jfs Ага, и будет куча времени и сил тратиться на объяснение очевидных вещей.  Вот здесь даже с [привествиями боролись](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/93/220571) и я представляю сколько сил затрачено. И "привет" со "зараннее спасибо" в посте многие считали необходимостью. И точно такие же по сути отговорки. У нас даже к грубости и "шутейкам" не всегда относятся как к нарушениям. У меня неоднократно отклоняли такие комментарии, просто часть из них удалили (если что не спрашивайте почему, я сам не знаю).

Comment: если вы думается что ваше мнение является очевидным и единственно правильным, то вы ошибаетесь — другие люди могут иметь мнение отличное от вашего. Иначе не было бы вашего вопроса в первую очередь.

Comment: @jfs Если создам вопрос про то, что "Вы случайно не индус?" звучит как минимум невежливо, то, уверен, тоже, наверняка, найдут отговорку. И скажут, что только на загнивающем западе, это звучит обидно. Скажут, что у нас, в нашей особенной культуре, — это норма. Вот даже в единственном ответе PashaPash мог пару строк уделить "Но вот по поводу "индуса" с вами согласен/не согласен потому что…" и т.д.. И мыслей по поводу необходимости комментариев отметить ответ галкой, когда это **уже сделано** тоже нет упонимания в нём. Хотя это 
всё можно сделать в пару коротких абзацев, без отдельных постов.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov про индуса - это явно была шутка, причем тот, кому ее адресовали, явно ее понял и не оскорбился. и случилась она еще на хэшкоде. чувство юмора у всех разное. но в этом конкретном случае видно, что комментатор просто пошутил, и не пытался никого оскорбить. и не оскорбил. шутку затерли еще вчера, так что вроде бы проблемы больше нет.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75023/discussion-on-question-by-vadim-ovchinnikov-----).

Comment: @jfs Я вот нашёл свой пост [Долой бесполезные комментарии вроде “спасибо](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4468/220571), которому уже больше года. Я тогда просто озвучил, что на enSO есть механика блока комментариев "спасибо" на этапе написания и что нам было бы неплохо её тоже внедрить.

Comment: Крайне знакомо. Неоднократно удивляло, что комментарии "спасибо" и более ненужные комментарии оставляют (из тех, на которые я ствил тревоги).

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov: в указанном сообщение не видно консенсуса. PashaPash написал: *«Обсуждение есть, решения со значительным перевесом и с аргументами кроме "модераторы должны" пока нет»* ¶ Учитывая, что комментариев со словом спасибо десятки тысяч, вручную модераторов по такому поводу не нужно дёргать. Если вас так достают подобные комментарии, то предложите *автоматически* по тревоге  «более не является необходимым» удалять подобные комментарии—это позволяет людям словами благодарность выразить и убрать позднее легко, если есть желание, хотя для не слишком популярных вопросов чистка не нужна.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В короткой перспективе «Спасибо!», конечно, имеет невероятно полезный эффект, ведь всегда приятно сделать что–то хорошое, что–то, что помогает людям вокруг нас. Только польза заканчивается как–только «Спасибо!» доставлено адресату, автору ответа. После этого комментарии подобные «Спасибо!» вносят шум в нашу базу знаний. Их следует *удалять* или *отмечать тревогой*.

#### Принятие ответа и голос «за» == «Спасибо! Ваш ответ мне очень помог!»

Голос «за» — это лучший способ сказать спасибо без добавления шума. Принятие ответа — лучший способ сказать *всему сообществу*, что ответ помог.

#### Что делать со «спасибо!» в комментариях?

К нашему сообществу каждую неделю присоединяется почти 1000 человек. Вероятно, [не все эти люди первым делом исследуют справочный центр](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7022/6): «Спасибо!» будут появляться, благодарность за оказанную нам помощь — человеческая сущность, что нельзя сказать про механику принятия ответа. С ростом популярности сообщества, все больше и больше людей будут задавать вопросы повторно, а значит и понимать механики сайта, [если мы вежливо подскажем коллегам как следует поступать при их первом взаимодействии с системой](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1222/6). Подсказав правильное действие, пожалуйста, отметьте комментарий тревогой или удалите его, так как...

#### Комментарий «Спасибо!» — это шум

В контексте вносимого шума в базу знаний, «Спасибо!» ничем не лучше других комментариев, не относящихся к вопросу или ответу. По этому поводу в справке «[Когда не следует оставлять комментарий?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)» имеется следующий заметка:

> **Когда *не* следует оставлять комментарий?**
>
> - ...
> - **Комплименты**, не содержащие новой информации («+1, великолепный ответ»); вместо этого, проголосуйте за данный ответ и [поделитесь своей репутацией](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).
> - ...

#### Как отблагодарить автора ответа и сообщество за помощь?

**Голос «за» и принятие ответа**

Для автора ответа *голос «за» и принятие ответа* равнозначны «спасибо!». Для сообщества и всех будущих посетителей сайта визуальные отметки у ответов несут огромную ценность — они позволяют ориентируются по голосам за ответы (сортировка) и дают понимание того, какой ответ решил поставленную проблему.

**Теплые слова**

На мой взгляд, теплые слова в адрес знатоков сообщества допустимы и приветствуются на любой *внешней платформе*. Например, на личной страничке ВКонтакте. Согласитесь, ведь всегда приятно, когда нас заслуженно хвалят публично реальные люди. Пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь рекомендовать авторам ответа «принять ответ, проголосовать "за" и рассказать друзьям, кто и где помог найти ответ на их вопрос».

---

#### Чем сложнее задача, тем лучше и дружнее сообщество!

Наше сообщество имеет очень интересную длинную историю, в которой были как взлеты, так и падения. Наличие большого числа унаследованных комментариев «Спасибо!» не является поводом к несоблюдению правил в настоящем. В прошлом мы не имели мощных инструментов модерирования, и даже бы если хотели, не смогли добиться того качества базы знаний, которое благодаря совместными усилиям получается достичь сегодня.

Перед нами явно вскрылась «спасибо»—проблема и мы можем ее решить не сводя с ума модераторов, например:

1. Провести очередные выборы модераторов.
2. Провести «субботник».

«Субботники» проводились во времена ХэшКода. В то время, после сессий (то есть два раза в год), мы проходились по вопросам за последние несколько месяцев и удаляли все закрытые «домашки», принимали ответы с комментариями «спасибо, это помогло!» под ними. Подобные «субботники» проводились и в рамках Stack Overflow на русском, например, [увеличение % принятых ответов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/956/6).

Уверен, правильно организовавшись, мы вместе сможем побороть данную проблему унаследованного прошлого (как и много других). Любая проблема — это прекрасная возможность проявить себя: чем интересней и проще решение, чем меньше монотонной работы оно от нас требует, тем более хорошими специалистами мы можем себя считать! Например, при необходимости, если сообщество посчитает это нужным, я буду рад предложить свою помощь в создании простого одностраничного сайта со списком всех комментариев со «спасибо», и парой кнопок: тревога и пропустить. Еще одним решением может быть скрипт для модераторов, который на основе уже удаленных комментариев проверяет тревоги в очереди и в полуавтоматическом режиме предлагает подтвердить удаление.

Интересных решений может быть сколь угодно много! Людей, способных и желающих предложить свою реализацию решения в сообществе более чем достаточно (чур я первый в очереди!) Самое главное — договориться о том, что мы видим проблемой, как и когда будем ее решать!

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, а что вы скажите по поводу отклоненения тревоги на уже неактуальную просьбу "отметить ответ как принятый" и трёх последних случаев? Или вы рекомендуете для этого создать отдельный пост (или посты)? Как вы относитесь к позиции действующего модератора, что фраза "А вы случайно не индус?" в комментариях — это [просто шутка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7046/#comment28112_7046)?

Comment: Если бы тревоги на комментарии обрабатывались сообществом, то скорость их "принятия" значительно возросла.

Comment: Ваш ответо *противопоставляет* "спасибо" и принятие ответа. Да, "спасибо *вместо* принятия ответа - это плохо. Но при этом - на всех примерах из вопроса, кроме одного, ответ принят. Т.е. из реально применимых аргументов остается "спасибо - это шум". Должны ли модераторы удалять "спасибо" целенаправленно? - прочесывать недавно прияные ответы, проводить субботники "удали спасибо"?

Comment: @PashaPash Это не в коем случае не противопоставление. На сайте заложена функция «Спасибо!», которая выражается в голосе «за» и принятие ответа. Дополнительное текстовое «Спасибо!» излишне, оно не нужно. Вероятно, это какой–то пережиток старых форумов, когда  это был единственный способ показать людям, как получилось решить задачку.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov огромная просьба - перестаньте, пожалуйста, разбрасываться обвинениями и мне приписывать позицию, которую я не высказывал. Я вам указал, что это была шутка, которую понял адресат. Я не говорил вам, что эта шутка удачная, и что такие шутки допустимы. Более того, именно я вырезал эту шутку из комментария. Если хотите развернутого ответа "какая позиция у модераторов относительно шутки N-летней давности, которую удалили" - оформите отдельный вопрос на мете.

Comment: Субботник — это общественное дело, которое следует обсуждать со всеми заинтересованными. Он должен иметь четкую цель, дату начала и конца. Это не регулярная активность.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky у нас 30+ тыс спасиб, из них 10+ коротких. и я бы не сказал, что все они оставлены давно. Т.е. люди продолжают благодарить в комментариях (ставя при этом зеленую галку). Я не представляю, как должен поступать модератор в случае, если участник регулярно пишет "спасибо" (и ставит при этом галку. Писать ему в личку "пожалуйста, перестаньте благодарить людей в комментариях"?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky т.е. без автоматизации мы борьбу со спасибами проиграем.

Comment: @PashaPash Вероятно, стоит это рассмотреть отдельно, чтобы составить хорошее объяснение. Про автоматизацию этого процесса уточню у коллег в самое ближайшее время.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky  это уже обсуждалось недавно -
 https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4468/

Comment: @PashaPash Больше года — это **не** недавно.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Это я пропустил данный вопрос из виду. Я все узнаю в ближайшее время (начну в понедельник 26 марта) и предложу какое–то решение, как только пойму, что есть, что мы можем сделать.

Comment: @PashaPash Ну я так понял ваш комментарий. Вы могли же просто и неразвёрнуто ответить, так чтобы вас можно было однозначно понять а-ля "Такие шутки недопустимы, вырезал".

Answer (score 4):

Люди склонны благодарить тех, кто дал им ответ. Комменты с благодарностями 
будут всегда, много и часто.

1. Сама необходимость их удаления сомнительна:

   > Комментарий устаревший, многословный или нежелательный по иной причине.

   Благодарность устарела со временем? Слишком многословна? Или нежелательна?
2. Модераторы не могут что-то удалить просто потому, что им это не нравится. Они не могут взять и придумать правило "спасибо запрещены". Модераторы обязаны действовать в рамках правил. А правила никак не запрещают оставлять благодарности в комментариях. Для подтверждения тревоги и для удаления комментария у модератора должна быть формальная причина. Причиной может быть

   - Явно прописаный в справке запрет на публикацию подобных комментариев. Сейчас запрета нет, [есть только рекомендация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).
   - Аргументированное обсуждение на мете, со значительным перевесом голосов в пользу "удалять". Обсуждение есть, решения со значительным перевесом и с аргументами кроме "модераторы должны" пока нет :(
3. Тревоги на комментариях - это тревоги, обрабатываемые модераторами вручную. Вы действительно считаете, что модераторы обязаны ежедневно, вручную сидеть и удалять чужие "спасибо" в комментариях по мере их поступления?

На сайте сейчас *32179* комментария со словом "спасибо" (из них больше 10к коротких). И еще 9433 со словом "пожалуйста". Для примера, я за все время модерирования обработал ~4600 тревог. Так что для борьбы с благодарностями в комментариях там придется избрать еще 4-5 модераторов - работа на пару лет им обеспечена :)

---

Тревоги (как модераторские, так и нет) стоит использовать в случае, если сообщение или комментарий представляют проблему своим существованием (вводят в заблуждение, оскорбляют кого-то, относятся к старой версии ответа и прочее, что действительно создает проблему). А не в случае, если в комментарии кто-то кого-то поблагодарил.

Comment: Полностью согласен! И ещё вообще не вижу причин удалять благодарности.

Comment: А то что комментарии должны по возможности удалятся, если не несут полезной информации вас не смущает? То есть всё по возможности следует писать в ответах, а остальное, если не содержит нужной информации — шум?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov я сомневаюсь, что у нас в правилах есть хоть что-то про удаление комментариев за то, что они не несут полезной информации. Требования ( пожелания) к отсутсвию шума - это скорее к содержимому вопросов и ответов.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov я к тому, что автор удаленного комментария может взять и написать на мете "за что мой коммент снесли? он же ничего не нарушал". что мы в таком случае должны отвечать? "он слишком шумел"? это не модерация, это произвол :)

Comment: @PashaPash А этот [прецедент](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258004/1548895) или подобного рода дискуссии к нам не относится? Мы особенное сообщество со своими правилами и уникальной культурой, которую не поймёт никто другой?

Comment: @Qwertiy Вы будете отклонять тревоги "более не является необходимым" на комментариях вида "спасибо"?

Comment: @PashaPash Вы будете отклонять тревоги "более не является необходимым" на комментариях вида "спасибо"?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, да, отклоняю и буду отклонять. Люди имеют право благодарить за ответ.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75024/discussion-on-answer-by-pashapash------).

Comment: Не удаление "спасибо" приносит отрицательный эффект, заключенный в неправильном понимании работы системы благодарностей. Да, Вы абсолютно правы, это каторжный труд удалить все спасибо на который нужен не один месяц (было бы отлично админам по базам пройтись скриптом, чтобы не делать этого вручную, но увы..) но и оставлять без внимания не стоит, так как люди подвержены подражанию (в хорошем смысле). В частности, многие, на мой взгляд, пишут спасибо  потому, что не знают как иначе выразить благодарность, а под каким-то ответом уже увидели спасибо.

Comment: Кроме этого многие, например, путают галку рейтинга и галку принятия ответа, поэтому и пишут "спасибо" 
Смысл so "вопрос-ответ, ничего лишнего". 
Например, к ответу появились очень важные замечания, но Вы попросту можете их не увидеть если перед ними будет много не нужных комментариев.

Comment: @Alex если спасибо приносят отрицательный эффект - должно быть запрещено их добавление. Усилия для решения проблемы длолжны быть соизмеримы с получаемым эффектом. Сейчас удаление спасибо требует участия двух людей (тревогнувший + модератор). А, например, удаление "заранее спасибо" из вопроса - всего одного человека с относительно невысоким уровнем репутации. Т.е. да, я понимаю жесткие требования к чистоте ответов. Но не до конца согласен с тем, что они же должны применяться к комментариям.

Answer (score 4):

Хочу прежде всего отметить, что отклонённые тревоги составляют около 10% всех тревог, поэтому говорить о последовательности в их модерации не приходится.

---

### Аргументы на [ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7047/220571) и в целом на противоположную позицию.

#### Большое количество комментариев вида "Спасибо" в целом

Много или мало комментариев вида "спасибо" — всё равно они вам попадаются. И вы тревогу на них вы можете либо принимать, либо отклонять.

А в чём именно проблема модерации? В том что именно этих комментариев очень много. И любой может их писать в любых количествах и нести наказания (и считаю, что это классно). Но это же большая нагрузка на модераторов это всё подчищать, так же? Ну да. Поэтому было бы классно внедрить то же, что и на enSO: автоматическое удаление комментариев по шаблону. Вот само [предложение у нас](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6966/220571), возможно внедрят, будет модератором жить попроще.

#### Санкции по поводу комментариев вида "Спасибо"

По поводу того, что кто-то написал комментарий "спасибо" — конечно, это не нарушение, и не надо ему делать замечаний. [пруф: Is it acceptable to write a thank you in a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126180/346987).

И всё-таки такие комменты нужно удалять. [пруф: Should a “thank you” comment be flagged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169999/346987). А также подобная ситуация на [главной мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279449/346987). Так как и без них можно обойтись. Так как они никак не добавляют информации и знаний. Это как "привет" и "спасибо" в самих постах и вода вроде "я новичок, не судите меня строго". Какая в них польза с точки зрения информативности? Некоторые комментарии под постами удаляются или переносятся в чат для концентрации внимания на контенте и содержащих технические сведенья, информативных комментариях. Принятие ответа и/или голос "за" — вот местный способ сказать спасибо. Остальное — за борт.

На enSO были некоторые подобные вещи ([раз](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338489/1548895), [два](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258004/1548895), [три](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326308/1548895) и т.д.). А представьте сколько модераторов затратили время ради этой [автоматизации флагов](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280546/1548895). И обратите внимание на точность автоматической обработки (99.61%), что свительствует не только о хорошо написанном и полезном боте, но и о слаженной модераторской работе.

#### Куча подобного рода комментариев на мете enSO

Это вполне нормально, просто потому что мета ценна именно самой дискуссием. А основные сайты — фактажем и сухими фактами.

---

Очень бы хотелось, чтобы были учтены также другие проблемы в моём посте:

- тревоги на комментариии "отметить ответ как принятый", когда это уже сделано.
- три последние тревоги, которые относятся к другого рода проблемам (не хотел делать отдельными постами), но на которые можно было бы ответить двумя абзацами.

Answer (score 4):

Поддерживаю Вадима в его позиции. Комментарии типа "спасибо" должны подлежать удалению так же как и ответы такого же характера. Да, комментарии менее заметны, чем ответы, но коли уж кто-то соизволил отметить его тревогой как "более не является необходимым", такую тревогу следует утвердить, а не отклонить. И для меня странно видеть, что уже двое действующих модераторов высказались за отклонение подобных тревог. Я не очень понимаю их посыл. Но могу попробовать предположить такие версии:

- наш сайт должен быть более человечным, чем англоязычный, поэтому написанное "спасибо" следует оставить;
- утверждение тревоги повлечёт за собой ещё шквал подобных тревог, а есть куда более серьёзные дела для модерации;
- опасение, что автоматика может применить какие-то санкции к авторам "спасиб" в комментариях, если тревогу подтвердить.

Я считаю, что ни одна из этих версий не должна применяться на практике при анализе тревоги на комментарий типа "спасибо". А если она применяется, то с модераторами стоит провести разъяснительную беседу.

Добавление автоматики, действующей на enSO, о которой также упомянул Вадим, будет хорошим подспорьем для модератора. Но для начала, модераторы должны выработать единую позицию о том, что "спасибо" в комментариях должны удаляться.

Если кто-то из них с этим не согласен, пусть это остаётся его личным мнением, но, как мне кажется, выдвигаясь на должность модератора надо иметь в виду, что личное мнение порой придётся отодвигать, и руководствоваться позицией сообщества, или хотя бы коллективным решением модераторов.

В любом случае, хотелось бы видеть это решение публично. Решение сообщества можно оценить по голосам на вопросе, а мнения модераторов (и менеджера сообщества) было бы хорошо опубликовать отдельными ответами, чтобы увидеть расстановку голосов, и понимать "власть с народом" или "власть против народа".

Comment: Комментарии же и так удаляются автоматически при накоплении определенного количества флагов. Добавлять ничего вроде не нужно

Comment: На основании чего модераторы "должны выработать единую позицию о том, что "спасибо" в комментариях должны удаляться"? На основании того, что относительно небольшому числу участников так захотелось? Это не основание, модераторы ничего исходя из этого делать не должны. Сейчас три из пяти модераторов против удаления спасибо. Обоснование - в моем ответе рядом. "Спасибо" не нарушает ничего.

Comment: Вопрос же не в том, что модераторам лень. Вопрос в том, что нет формального повода эти комментарии удалять. Чтобы был формальный повод - нужно хотя бы обсуждение на мете, в котором написано, чем так эти комментарии мешают, что заслуживают тревоги. Описано для тех, кто пишет "спасибо" в комментах, так, чтобы модераторы могли бы привести им это обсуждение в качестве обоснования удалению.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75025/discussion-on-answer-by-alexolut------).

Comment: Минимум 4 модератора против удаления (2 высказались в этой теме, ещё один в другой и ещё один отклонил часть тревог из вопроса). Так что нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy да что ж вы всё загадками-то разговариваете.

Comment: @Qwertiy Хотел бы подчеркнуть, что у нас нет институтов подобных Думе, где собираются люди, представляющие интересы коллег, обладающие правом решать за наделивших их властью людей. Мы принимаем решения коллективно и голос «за» любого участника имеет одинаковый вес. Более того, [важен не столько голос, сколько обоснование, почему мы должны следовать этим правилам, а не другим](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6899/6). Фраза вида «4 модератора считают по другому» не вносит пользы до тех пор, пока каждый из модераторов не опубликовал ответ с обоснованиями.

Comment: @PashaPash а почему комментарии так странно в чат перенеслись? Некоторые до переноса остались.

Comment: @alexolut старался перенести до начала флуда и оставить заплюсованное. сорри если что