# Зачем нам удаление комментариев со "спасибо"?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, модерация, комментарии

Как правило, таких комментариев не больше одного под ответом и они никому не мешают. Так зачем же нам надо городить [целую систему](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7095/178988), да ещё и потенциально дающую false-positive-результаты - ведь проверяться будет только вхождение слов, а не смысл комментария, чтобу убирать то, что не мешает?

Предлагаю вообще не удалять комментарии со "спасибо" кроме случаев, когда они прям явно мешают (например, идут вперемешку с полезным конткентом).

Кстати, как уже выяснилось [в прошлый раз](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7047/178988), минимум 4 модератора против удаления.

Comment: Напоминаю, что голоса на вопросе [не выражают](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6896/178988) отношение к ситуации. Чтобы высказать своё мнение, голосовать надо за ответы. Также ответы можно дополнять аргументами за соответствующий вариант.

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что в общем случае [голосование само по себе за что–либо бесполезно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6899/6). Важно не как думает большинство, а почему люди так считают. Ответы для голосования ниже — шум и не добавляют никаких новых знаний о проблеме. Они не нужны.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky тогда стоит запретить добавление таких комментариев (спасибо + коротких), а не придумывать систему для их удаления с потенциальными false positive. Сомневаюсь, что удалять коммент за наличие слова "код" нем - это адекватное решение проблемы спасиб.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, ответы содержат некое обоснование, а ещё их можно дополнять.

Comment: @Qwertiy Было бы очень здорово, если бы ответы были дополнены развернутыми идеями, поясняющими вывод (за что голосуют), но исходя из нашего предыдущего опыта, вероятно, они не будут дополнены. Сама постановка этого вопроса говорит: голосуй и уходи, но не поясняй, делись идеями и участвуй в дискуссии, а именно это, сбор доводов за и против, нам и нужно.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, вообще-то я особо не вижу причин удалять или оставлять помимо мнения каждого "они мне мешают" или "они мне не мешают". Ну и ещё аргументы про false positive для автоудаления. Если у тебя есть ещё какие-то обоснования - просто отредактируй соответствующие ответы.

Comment: @Qwertiy А в чём вообще смысл именно голосования? Декларирование личной позиции можно было бы просто изложить в вопросе безо всяких самоответов и вариантов.

Answer (score 22):

## Не удалять

Комментарии "спасибо" не мешают и их не надо удалять.

Благодарность важна как для автора ответа, так и для тех, кто видит этот ответ. Помимо того, в комментарии кроме благодарности могут быть отмечены некоторые важные аспекты самого ответа, либо его отличие от других, что ценно само по себе.

И ещё один интересный факт, который я чувствовал, но только сейчас в полной мере осознал. **В чём разница между плюсом и комментарием "Спасибо"?** Вот сижу, листаю вопросы, читаю какие-то ответы, думаю "о, какой интересный способ - поставлю-ка я ему плюсик" — и собственно ставлю. По идее, это верно. А теперь через неделю я натыкаюсь на тот же ответ когда он мне нужен, у ответа куча плюсов, пытаюсь его использовать, а реально "упс.. так не работает, какая-то деталь не учтена". А что такое комментарий "Спасибо, помогло"? Это опыт реального человека, который применил этот ответ на практике. И плюсы на этом комментарии — таки же люди, которые применили и которым помогло. По сути, комментарий со "спасибо" даже более ценен, чем плюс и по своей сути находится где-то ближе к зелёной галочке, чем к плюсику.

Comment: Ничего не понял. Зачем вообще "спасибо", если есть галочка? Если автор поставил галочку, значит ответ работает, не?

Comment: @Suvitruf, галочку может поставить только автор вопроса, а написать "спасибо, помогло" может любой человек, кому ответ помог. Принят может быть только один ответ, а написать "спасибо, это тоже работает" можно у нескольких. А тут ещё момент: "это тоже работает" - обычный комментарий, для рассмотрения модератором, а "спасибо, это тоже работает" - уже подпадает под регулярку и удаляется автоматически по первой тревоге любого проходящего мима пользователя? Брррррррр...

Comment: Почему-то "спасибо это работает" у меня вызывает аналогию из Dark Souls "illusory wall ahead" )

Answer (score 11):

## Удалять, но только вручную

Комментарии "спасибо" мешают, но не настолько, чтобы доверять их удаление автоматике. Путь лучше будет некоторое количество "спасибо", чем потенциальное удаление полезных комментариев.

Comment: Так это же не работает! Иначе тема бы и не всплыла. Ставишь тревогу, а модератор ее просто отклоняет и всё...

Comment: @АндрейNOP: что значит "отклоняет"? Если нет решения сообщества, то что модераторы должны делать? Можете привести пример когда модераторы систематически вопреки мнению сообщества  поступали (обратите внимание: в текущем случае нет консенсуса: даже когда позиция одной из сторон представлена формальной отпиской -- без адекватной аргументации (что в моём представлении делает голосование недействительным) -- даже в таком случае голоса практически равны на данный момент.

Comment: @jfs, то и значит. Вот топик: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7046/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP: и где там консенсус вы нашли? Или вы считаете, что поведение модераторов в камне высечено и не может измениться и поэтому не нужно пытаться найти какие правила могут улучшить сайт?

Answer (score 4):

### Удалять, в том числе автоматически

Автоматически должно удаляться только то, что очевидно. Ложные срабатывания здесь недопустимы, иначе смысла в автоматизации нет. Автоматически должно удаляться только то, что является комментарием-комплиментом в чистом виде без полезных сведений. Комментарий может содержать "спасибо", но при этом содержать полезную критику или просто сведения (как дополнение). Должно проверяться только полное соответствие, а не наличие подстроки. Допустим, комментарий "Большое спасибо!" вполне можно удалять автоматически.

В любом случае комментарий-комплимент без полезных сведений со 100%-ной вероятностью никак автоматически не определить. Поэтому крайне важна слаженность "автоматики" и модераторов.

### Позиция модераторов

> минимум 4 модератора против удаления

Позиция модераторов может быть любой. Главное, чтобы их действия не противоречили правилам. Поэтому, к сожалению, есть вероятность для модераторов делать то, с чем не согласны. Аргументация удаления на соответствие правилам приведена в [ответе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7052/220571).

Answer (score -13):

## Удалять, в том числе автоматически

Комментарии "спасибо" мешают настолько, что их обязательно надо удалять, даже если вместе с ними будут удаляться полезные комментарии (false positive при автоматической проверке).