# Чем помешал комментарий?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, комментарии

Есть мой ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/819996/186083

Есть комментарий к нему:

> А что если мы не знаем, что там и какие символы, может текст приходит откуда-то, или записывается кем-то.

Был мой комментарий, как ответ на этот комментарий с просьбой задать этот вопрос другим отвечающим, так как все ответы включают в себя использование символов ограничителей предложения.

Так же в комментарии была указана ссылка на википедию с определением что такое предложение, объясняющая использование ограничительных символов.

Вопрос: Чем мой комментарий вам помешал, что его удалили?

P.S. В комментарии не было грубости!

Comment: @PashaPash, вот и первые жертвы.

Comment: А я предупреждал.

Comment: @Qwertiy, откатим эту инициативу!

Comment: Я изменил метки и полагаю, что [tag:удаление-ответов] здесь не подходит, вы так тоже считаете, @Visman?

Comment: перенес [комментарии, не имеющие прямого отношения к вопросу, в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76696/discussion-on-question-by-visman---).

Comment: @Other судя по [прошлому вопросу со статистикой удаления](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7155/178988), механизм, в целом, работает. Но regex, imho, стоит подправить.

Comment: @PashaPash, пришёл Николас и заставил Вас потереть негативный комменты о себе? И типа сам ни при чём :) И, судя по тому же вопросу, механизм вообще плохо работает. 50 комментариев - это выборка? И в ответах разнесли в пух и прах удаления.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Удалено по тревоге одного из обычных пользователей и обработано Духом.

- [Автоматическое удаление комментариев по тревоге «более не является необходимым»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7095/178988)
- [Две недели с удаления более не нужных комментариев с заданными словами без проверки модераторами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7155/178988)
- [Зачем нам удаление комментариев со "спасибо"?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7097/178988)
- [Прекратите редактировать мои «хрен» и «фиг»! >:(](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7140/178988)

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 3):

Большое спасибо за то, что написали об этом! Действительно, ваш комментарий был удален [автоматически](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7095/) как более не являющийся необходимым обычным участником сообщества.

Удаление никак не отразится на вас. Данная тревога предназначена для удаления комментариев, которые «устарели». Например, если вы перенесли информацию из комментария в ваш ответ, а сам комментарий не удалили или если вы пояснили другому участнику ответ, но информация из комментария не может/не должна быть перенесена в ответ (как я понимаю, в вашем случае именно это послужило причиной тревоги).

Если вы считаете, что это ложное срабатывание, пожалуйста, дайте знать комментарием к этому ответу. Я свяжусь с автором тревоги и мы попробуем понять, имело место ли недопонимание между участниками или это ошибка настройки «автоматики».

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что (предположительно) единичные ложные срабатывания будут обрабатываться вручную?

Comment: Предположительно — потому что реагирование ускоренного удалятора на слова `вопрос` и `ответ` будет несколько мешать писать комментарии вида «Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос название, версию и разрядность операционной системы». Из-за этого, кстати, необходимо менять процедуру уточнения вопроса, перейдя к принципу «разузнать всё в комментариях, потом чьими-нибудь усилиями махом перенести всё в вопрос, удалив комментарии». Ничего такого в этом нет, но этот регламент необходимо будет как-то донести до *всех* участников, включая новых, только-только получивших возможность комментировать.

Comment: Кстати, можно добавить вывод некоего обобщённого всплывающего предупреждения при попытке отправить комментарий с нежелательными словами? Не указывать на конкретное слово (чтобы не было обхода системы), а напоминать про необходимость достойного общения. Этак, *Пожалуйста, не посылайте вопрошающих в поисковые системы и на сторонние сайты* (при попадании слов наподобие `гугл*`), или *Пожалуйста, не просите поштучно дописывать дополнительную информацию. Сначала соберите всё необходимое в комментариях, а потом перенесите в вопрос/ответ сразу всё.* (при попадании слов типа `вопрос` или `ответ`).

Comment: ... это должно устранить абсолютно все неожиданные удаления (система честно предупреждала перед публикацией, а далее все риски лежат на вопрошающем) и связанные с этим недопонимания.