# Причины модераторского сообщения и отклонения тревог на ненужных комментариях

Tags: поддержка, модерация, комментарии, тревоги, модераторский-произвол

Вчера поставил тревоги на [несколько комментариев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1180615/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8#comment2054304_1180615) по причине:

> Он больше не нужен.
>
> Этот комментарий устарел, порождает бесконечные
> дискуссии или не относится к данному сообщению.

Спустя какое-то время получил следующее модераторское сообщение:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Через примерно минуту после сообщения дал ответ:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А также поставил тревоги на комментарии [благодарю!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1180615/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8#comment2054389_1180615) и [пожалуйста :)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1180612/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-python/1180625#comment2054322_1180625) примерно в то же время. Они тоже были отклонены.

До сих пор не получил ответа в модераторских сообщениях, что интерпретирую как игнорирование, потому что все [модераторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), которые могли написать это сообщение, были онлайн не менее одного раза с момента ответа 21 час назад ([@Nick Volynkin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/nick-volynkin) и [@Nofate](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1984/nofate) не были онлайн около недели, так что написать не могли). Также [писал в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55614429#55614429) по этому поводу, но модераторы не ответили и там.

Поэтому спрашиваю тут:

1. Почему 2 тревоги на скрине посчитали ложными? Разве информация об учебном заведении ТСа является необходимой?
2. Почему 2 тревоги на благодарность и ответ на благодарность отклонили? Разве уже не [обсуждалось](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7046/398802), что такие комментарии не нужны?
3. Почему меня подозревают в использовании ботов?
4. Если я продолжу генерацию тревог, то меня забанят? Или что понимается под "необходимыми действиями"?
5. Почему мне не отвечают ни в модераторских сообщениях, ни в чате?

Comment: А может такое быть, что такое сообщение присылается автоматически? Просто Дух тоже (вроде как) модератор.

Comment: @EOF об этом не думал. Может быть, хотя скрин похож на модераторское меню, вряд ли бот бы такой скрин генерировал. В любом случае, это отвечает только на последний и частично на 3 вопрос

Comment: Так это скрин? Я думал что ссылки кликабельные. Тогда скорее всего живой модератор.

Comment: На SO правила пишутся на коленке и интерпретирует их каждый по своему. Нет стандарта, нет равноправия, нет справедливости. Это касается предыдущего модераторского состава. Как будет сейчас, время покажет. Но создается такое впечатление, что мало что поменяется. У руководства слова расходятся с делом потому что. Уверен, мой комментарий возможно будет удален, как и многие другие. Потому как они кому-то неудобны.

Comment: @Sevastopol' скорее, потому, что в них нет никакой конкретики и голословные утверждения (;

Comment: @EOF, нет, письмо присылает человек. А вот за большое количество отклонённых тревог ограничения на тревоги наложит автоматика.

Comment: Когда-то я тоже решил побороться за чистоту сайта и сделал пару тревог на ненужные комментарии. Тревоги тоже были отклонены. В общем, забей. Мусор остаётся.

Comment: Мне тоже "благодарю" отклонили. То ли @Qwertiy взялся за дело ;) (он за "спасибо"), то ли  модераторам пофигу ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, я пока боюсь отклонять тревоги, которые формально правильные. Но может времена начинают меняться?)

Comment: Новый модсостав включился в работу :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Да, это новый модсостав :)

1. Во первых, я получил сообщение от модератора enSO, что согласно их аналитике подобные сообщения генерируются роботом (был даже приведен пример скрипта генерирующего подобные однотипные "тревоги"). Конечно, я не уверен, что тревоги генерируются роботом и на всякий случай предупредил ТС.
2. Действительно подобные однотипные тревоги отвлекают других гораздо более сложных кейсов, особенно когда их много - в какие-то дни их количество доходило до 20-30...
3. Я не считаю, что комментарии (даже тупые) стоит удалять. Главное чтобы они не нарушали правил сообщества (а они не нарушают). Я придерживаюсь логики, что комментарии это часть дискуссии, а дискуссия часть человеческого общения - за которую я ратовал, когда избирался.
4. Банить за это я не собираюсь. Вообще бан это уже крайняя мера, за все время (3 недели) - я его применил только 1 раз.

**Update**

Политика по отношению к комментариям (моя):

Не считаю, что комментарии стоит удалять, даже если они не относятся к теме сообщения - это часть человеческого общения, все мы люди и человеки и нам кроме сухих ответов/вопросов нужно и обычное общение. Есть конечно 3 исключения:

1. Грубость, нетерпимость, хамство и т.д. - это безусловное удаление комментария с перспективой бана
2. Если об этом просит ТС, под ТС (топик-стартером) - я понимаю, того кто задал вопрос (а не того кто ответил). Если ТС считает, что комментарий лишний - я удалю.
3. Длинные комментарии - переносятся в чат (с предварительным удалением)

Comment: Разве модератор не должен следовать решениям сообщества/компании в лице Николаса на мете, если такое решение есть? А не руководствоваться своим отличающимся или совпадающим с этими решениями мнением

Comment: @dIm0n я стал модератором не благодаря Николасу или вам лично. Я пришел с некой программой, народ поддержал программу и я ее реализую - нравится вам это или нет.

Comment: Обсуждение кто на каком курсе в вопросе "Динамические структуры данных" все же не по теме, так что по правилам должно быть удалено. Ибо по правилам в комментариях запрещена "вторая дискуссия" (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Формулировка какая-то кривая, конечно. Но да, флагать каждый комментарий в таком случае это перебор. По сути, нужен один флаг "снесите всё не по теме под этим вопросом".

Comment: В корне не согласен по комментариям: формулировка флага: "этот комментарий больше не нужен или порождает бесконечные дискуссии". Если комментарий удовлетворяет данному критерию - он должен быть снесен по тревоге, даже если он не нарушает правил сообщества.

Comment: Тревога от модератора enSO была НЕ про dIm0n.

Comment: Тревогу на [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1183341/Не-понимаю-почему-выводится-крупное-число-перед-решением#comment2059571_1183342) и [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1183343/отсутствует-оператор-соответствующий-этим-операндам/1183344#comment2059573_1183344) комментарии тоже вы отклонили?

Comment: А что надо отчитываться?

Comment: @Barmaley <используйте собаку + ник, чтобы пришло уведомление> там такие же ненужные комментарии, что и здесь. И если это вы, то получается, что вопрос не имел смысла, раз продолжается то же самое

Comment: 1) @dIm0n я знаю как пользоваться системой. 
2) про ненужные комментарии - это ваше личное мнение

Comment: @Barmaley большинство плюсов у ответа, отражающего моё мнение, т.е. сообщество согласно, что тревоги не были ложными. Почему тогда продолжается отклонение?

Comment: Голоса в мете не являются отражением мнения всего сообщества. Это некая выборка (на мой личный взгляд не совсем репрезентативная). В мете активны не все, а всего лишь часть. Свое мнение я изложил в ответе, это часть если угодно моей предвыборной программы :) - так что я ее выполняю.

Comment: Да, и кстати, с чего вы взяли, что ваше мнение поддержано? Есть нейтральный взгляд @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, есть ваш вопрос, который безусловно интересен, есть мой ответ, который не понравился вам и вашему суппортеру и что?

Comment: <мне не приходят уведомления, когда вы не указываете собаку + ник =/> если мета не отражает мнение сообщества, то что его отражает? В вашей предвыборной программе вы не говорили, что будете отклонять такие тревоги, так что за это никто не голосовал. Взял с того, что у ответа @Suvitruf +10, а тут -2

Comment: @dIm0n мета отражает мнение сообщества. Но модераторы, в принципе, не обязаны ему следовать, могут руководствоваться своими принципами. Каждый модератор сам для себя эти вещи решает.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik а мнению Николаса обязаны?

Comment: @dIm0n Николас, при всем уаажении к нему всего лишь наемный сотрудник SO, да он один из создателей ресурса хэшкод, который был в свое время куплен SO. Принципиально лишь то, что SO это самоуправляемое сообщество, в котором действуют выбранные модераторы, один из которых я...

Comment: @dIm0n нет. Николай может что-то советовать, но приказывать не может — модераторы не наёмные сотрудники. От них требуется лишь соблюдение правил и наблюдение за тем, чтобы другие участники правила соблюдали. Делать они это могу на своё усмотрение, руководствуясь личными принципами и (если захотят) решениями на Мете.

Comment: @dIm0n см. апдейт ответа.

Answer (score 12):

Модераторы по-разному к такому относятся. Некоторые считают, что такие тревоги отвлекают от более важных тревог. По пунктам же:

1. Тревоги не ложные.
2. Не нужны.
3. Потому что, вероятно, часто используете такой тип тревог.
4. Нет. За это забанить не могут.
5. Вероятно, считают, что разговор окончен.

P.S. все сообщения подобные пишут живые модераторы.

Comment: Ну вот, только вы отложили ромб — началось ;)

Comment: Чтобы не  отвлекали  от более важных "дел насущных" есть скрипт, который по регулярке удаляет комментарии по тревоге автоматом. Может пришло время его улучшитъ? Некоторые даже умеют им "пользоваться" (это я об авторе комментария выше).

Comment: @0xdb это больше не ко мне. Меня тревоги вообще никогда особо не напрягали.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik Конечно, это не к вам лично.  Это к этой фразе -  _тревоги отвлекают от более важных тревог_.

Comment: @0xdb не думаю, что кто-то будет ту регулярку дорабатывать)